# App Inventor BluetoothLE receive 2 values from Arduino 101

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, app-inventor

does anyone know how I could receive 2 or more values from the Arduino 101 using BluetoothLE.

If I try to read values from different service_uuid or characteristic_uuid, there is no possibility to distinguish in the callback function which values was the received one.

Do you have a solution for this?

Greetings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Print 2 values separating them with (",") or any other symbol. create an emply list, use split text at a block and put the symbol u used. put the 1st value at index 1 in the list 2nd value in index 2